Running another method in a View after a form is saved using CBVs - DJANGO
I am trying to run another method after a form is saved:
The method inc_rec gets the id field created from the class based view once saved

Once form is saved: I want to retrieve all records in the table Checklist
Iterate through each of the rows and add the records to the All_Inspection table and updating the company id.

I am a bit stuck - as I have tried using signals, and I have tried to override, but somewhere there is a gap.
Help appreciated - Thanks in advance.
class ParishCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Company
    fields = ['str_Company_Name', 'str_City','str_post_code']
    #success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('form_valid')
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def inc_rec(self):
        Checklist = Checklist.objects.all()
        id = self.request.id
        for rec in Checklist:
            new_rec=All_Inspection(str_status=rec.str_status, str_check=rec.str_check, str_comment='',company_id=id)
            new_rec.save() 

I am expecting new records to be added into ALL_Inspection table once the form is saved with the new created item.

If you look at the source code of the CreateView and follow through a few step you will find that form_valid() is defined in the ModelFormMixin where it saves the form, then calls its own parent class (FormMixin). This returns a HttpResponseRedirect with the defined success_url.
You can keep this response aside until you need to return as below:
def form_valid(self, form):
    print("form valid")
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    response = super().form_valid(form)
    # All the logic you want to run after the form is saved
    return response


Thanks simalpas, I tried that but had errors so I reverted to use the following statements before the return response
code

def form_valid(self, form):
   form.instance.author = self.request.user
   parish = form.save(commit=False)
   parish.user_id = self.request.user.id
   parish.save()
   entry = Company.objects.get(pk=parish.id)
   print(str(parish.id))
   Checklists = Checklist.objects.all()
   for rec in Checklists:
       new_rec=All_Inspection(str_status=rec.str_status, str_check=rec.str_check, str_comment='',company_id=entry)
       new_rec.save()
   return super().form_valid(form)


Resolved now - I found a method which captures in state value for the pre save parish = form.save(commit=False).  I could then capture the id that was created and process further.
